# Keys Triggered With No Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I want to trigger down arrow key then enter key. It  triggers but does not show any effect.

After geolocator suggestion, I want to move the first suggestion and fire the enter key. Please check the image for more info.

```
   function showPosition(position) 
   {

      lat=position.coords.latitude; 
      lng=position.coords.longitude;
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
      {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
          {
             if (results[1])
             {
                var address= (results[1].formatted_address);
                document.getElementById('pick-auto').value=address;
                $('#pick-auto').focus();

                setTimeout(
                  function() 
                  {
                      var e = $.Event('keydown');
                      e.which = 40; // Character 'A'
                      $('#pick-auto').trigger(e);

                        var f = $.Event('keypress');
                        f.which = 13; // Character 'A'
                        $('#pick-auto').trigger(f);
                  }, 5000);
              }
         }
    });
  }
```

[You can check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2odx3.png)

Comment: What do your listeners look like? Are they `onkeydown` or e.g `onkeypress` or `onpinput` ?

Comment: those now works but don't get affect. thanks for reply.